# Directional derivatives exist at any direction and locally bounded implies continuity.

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complex normed linear spaces. If $f \colon X \to Y$ is locally bounded and the Gateaux derivative
$$D f(x, v) := \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(x + zv) - f(x)}{z}$$ exists for every $v \in X$ and $x \in X$. Show that f is continuous.

I have no idea about how to use the locally bounded contition. Can any one gives some help? Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using the Hahn-Banach theorem and mean-value theorem, which gives me $\|f(x) - f(x_0)\| \leq \sup_{y \in [x_0, x]} \|Df(y, x-x_0\| \|x-x_0\|$. But it can't give me the continuity on $x_0$ since I have no information about the limit of $\sup_{y \in [x_0, x]} \|Df(y, x-x_0\|$.